# HERE Maps Intermodal Routing API v8 Example does not work (API Key Auth)

Tags: here-api

HERE Maps newbie here,

I have set up an account and tried to run the example for intermodal routing ([Link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/intermodal-routing/dev_guide/index.html))

I basically copy pasted the GET request into the browser and replaced {YOUR_API_KEY} with a key that I have generated in advance({MY_API_KEY}):

```
https://intermodal.router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apyKey={MY_API_KEY}&alternatives=2&destination=52.40358749909618,13.058351363288239&origin=52.53105637575095,13.384944833815183
```

This is the response that I am getting:

```
{"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"Bearer token invalid. Bearer missing or bearer value missing."}
```

Other API requests work like a charm with the same API key - e.g. the below normal route request works:

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey={MY_API_KEY}&transportMode=car&origin=52.5308,13.3847&destination=52.5264,13.3686
```

I also tried to replace "apyKey=" with "apiKey=" in the topmost request, but the response stays the same...

Am I missing something (else) or is there something broken with the apiKey Auth for this API?

Best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with `apikey`, so:

`https://intermodal.router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey={MY_API_KEY}&alternatives=2&destination=52.40358749909618,13.058351363288239&origin=52.53105637575095,13.384944833815183`

---

Normally `apiKey` or `apikey` should work, but it seems the service doesn't accept the one with capital "K"

`apyKey` looks like documentation issue.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm, :).